# Powershell: Verbose equivalent for the '&' call operator?

Tags: powershell, operators

Is there a verbose *exact* equivalent for the '&' call operator to use with scriptblocks?

Like this pseudocode:

```
CALL { "Arguments are:"; $args; } One Two "Three word argument"
```

To replace:

```
& { "Arguments are:"; $args; } One Two "Three word argument"
```

**EDIT:**

The reason I need this is to pass batch file arguments to powershell.
This fails:

```
@ECHO OFF
START powershell.exe -noexit -Command "^& { \"Batch file arguments are:\"; $args; } %*"
```

I can do it like this, but the first method is cleaner:

```
@ECHO OFF
START powershell.exe -noexit -Command Invoke-Expression $('^& { \"Batch file arguments are:\"; $args; } %*')
```

I know I still need to escape quotes for long arguments.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass batch file arguments to PowerShell like this:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SET PS_ARGS=%*
IF DEFINED PS_ARGS SET PS_ARGS=%PS_ARGS:"=\"%
START powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "& { \"Batch file arguments are:\"; $args; } %PS_ARGS%"
```

It will escape quotes so you can call it like:

```
MyBatch.bat one two "Three word argument"
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a "verbose" equivalent I know of is:

```
{ "Arguments are:"; $args; }.InvokeReturnAsIs("One","Two","Three word argument")
```

Comment: This has the same output as `& { "Arguments are:"; $args; } One Two "Three word argument"`

Comment: @AndyArismendi - OP is not talking about output being verbose, but the syntax being so.

Comment: If it didn't produce the same output, it wouldn't be an exact equivalent.  Did I misread the question?

Comment: Oh, just read @manojlds comment. My bad was thinking output from the scriptblock. Sounds like the OP is looking for the alias equivalent for `&`. You read the question right :-)

Comment: I saw that. Apparently that was posted while I was still doing that "search and destory" thing that I try to pass off as "hunt and peck".

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function that will make the pseudo code that you mentioned to work:

```
function call ($script){
    & $script $args
}

call { "Arguments are:"; $args; } One Two "Three word argument"
```

Comment: Should that '&' be a '.' ?  Seems like the & would cause you to end up running the script block in a grandchild scope.  You'd probably never notice unless the script block is explicitly looking for someting in the immediate parent scope.  Or maybe I'm just picking nits.

Comment: @mjolinor - Depends on how it's to be used? Psake does the same with exec wrapper - https://github.com/psake/psake/blob/master/psake.psm1

Comment: Probably.  I'm not sure if the scope it's going to run in is part of the requirment for being an exact equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the ampersand. This should work fine:

```
@ECHO OFF
START powershell.exe -noexit -Command "& { \"Batch file arguments are:\"; $args; } %*"
```

if you call it this way:

```
mybatch.cmd One Two 'Three word argument'
```